# RegEx - Match all text within group of keywords

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match all of the text from the words `Problem Description` all the way to the new line after the `Action Plan`...this RegEx is not working...

```
(?=.*\bProblem Description\b)(?=.*\bBusiness Impact\b)(?=.*\bTroubleshooting\b)(?=.*\bCurrent Status\b)(?=.*\bAction Plan\b).+
```

This is the text that I am trying to match...I want to return all of this text...Is there a way to match by a sequence of keywords?

```
Problem Description: Customer reported an problem with a card that was receiving a "broken chip error message".

Business Impact: Unknown

Troubleshooting: Collected the alarm history and the debug logs.

Current Status: Customer switched slots with several differnt cards and isolated it down to two defective cards. 

Action Plan: once the completed form is returned will issue RMA.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with your sample:

```
(Problem Description:)(.|\s)*(Action Plan:.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all of the text I didn't need the lookbehind...also needed dot all to include line breaks.

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(Problem Description)(.*.)(Action Plan)(.*.)"

test_str = ("Problem Description: Customer reported an problem with a card that was receiving a \"broken chip error message\".\n\n"
    "Business Impact: Unknown\n\n"
    "Troubleshooting: Collected the alarm history and the debug logs.\n\n"
    "Current Status: Customer switched slots with several differnt cards and isolated it down to two defective cards. \n\n"
    "Action Plan: once the completed form is returned will issue RMA.")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```